# Church-style CoC with axiom for induction over Church-encoded unit, is it consistent?

Tags: type-theory, calculus-of-constructions

If we start with the Calculus of Constructions, and then use the following definitions for the Church-encoded Unit:

```
UnitType = (t : *) -> t -> t
Unit = \(t : *) (x : t). x
```

And the add the following construct `indUnit`:

```
G |- P : UnitType -> *
G |- pu : P Unit
G |- u : UnitType
--------------
G |- indUnit P pu u : P u
```

With reduction rule:

```
indUnit P pu Unit ~> pu
```

Basically this adds induction over the Church-encoded unit type.

1. Is this consistent?
2. If we change the reduction rule to:

```
indUnit P pu x ~> x (P x) pu (if x is a closed term)
```

Is it still consistent?

It seems to me that this is consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's consistent. Probably the easiest account is in my 2013 CSL paper with Derek Dreyer, [*Internalizing Parametricity in the Extensional Calculus of Construction*](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~nk480/final-csl-internalizing-parametricity.pdf), which is all about adding this style of parametricity axiom to the CoC.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. I had a small question about that paper: at the end of 5.3 it says "Details are given in the appendix.", but I am unable to find these details in the appendix.